# Cut cube into half but keep vertices of all faces

Tags: modeling

In Edit Mode, when I use Loop Cut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to cut cube at half, when I remove one of the sides, it results into the following:

[image: Half]

The problem is that one face is missing. I tried Sculpt Mode and Grab tool doesn't do it correctly. I did try pressing <kbd>V</kbd> according to [youtu.be](https://youtu.be/mrHQRJL0W84?t=45), but it's sticking what exists instead of recovering the cut vertices of the missing face.

Also, I could try creating new cubes, but it'd be in pratice easier to split the existing one, according to the video I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior.  Select the 4 vertices that surround where the missing face would go and enter <kbd>F</kbd> to create the face.

Before:

[image: half cube]

After:

[image: half cube with new face]